# declaring div in c# with onclick event

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, html

i m trying to create a div container in c# codebehind.i want the div container to raise a javascript event onclick once its clicked.its working fine.below is the code where a javascript function "ds()" is called with no parameters.the problem is that i want to pass a parameter to javascript function.I dont know how to accomplish it.Kindly facilitate me.

```
//string userIcon = "gbn";

sb.Append(userIcon + @"<div onclick=""ds()"" style='background-color: #EFEFEF; padding: 10px;'>" + "<a href=#>" + "MubbshirAbbs" + "</a></div><br>");

Literal1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

The Javascript function is this:

```
function ds()
{
  var a="";alert("123");
  document.getElementById("TextBox1").style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

Kindly let me know how can i add a parameter in the div onclick function.

Answer (score 1):

Alter the C# code:

```
sb.Append(userIcon);
sb.Append(@"<div onclick=""ds(");
sb.Append("'clicked'");
sb.Append(@")"" style='background-color: #EFEFEF; padding: 10px;'>");
sb.Append("<a href=#>");
sb.Append("MubbshirAbbs");
sb.Append("</a></div><br>");
```

Alter the javascript:

```
function ds(param)
{
  var a="";alert("123");
  document.getElementById("TextBox1").style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get your problem, can't you just do this?:

```
sb.Append(userIcon + @"<div onclick=""ds(" + parameter + ")"" style='background-color: #EFEFEF; padding: 10px;'>" + "<a href=#>" + "MubbshirAbbs" + "</a></div><br>");
Literal1.Text = sb.ToString();
function ds(parameter)
{
var a="";alert(parameter);
document.getElementById("TextBox1").style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```